# npm Fetch Failed. Error Code 504

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, share-button

I'm trying to implement this plugin called [Share Button](https://github.com/carrot/share-button) from npm my running `https://github.com/carrot/share-button`. However after doing that and waiting around 5mins I get the following output:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/i/-/i-0.3.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 504
⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠇ fetchMetadata: WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 504
```

Does anyone know why this would happen and a way to get round it? Thanks

Comment: What's the exact command you're running?

Comment: npm i --save-dev share-button is the command that produces the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tried

```
npm i --save-dev share-button
```

like me. Try using the github repo like that

```
npm install --save-dev carrot/share-button
```

That works without an error on my machine :)

Comment: Yes! It works! Congratulations :) Now, why do you have to write the carrot/ in front? Their documentation doesn't even specify that?

Comment: Its the github url. You can always use 'npm install githubname/reponame' if it is from a github repo. Just type 'npm help install' for the npm documentation. They can expain it better :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute the command below:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

That will get packages *npm install* over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm still getting the same error. It's just hanging there.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you also get a 504 error if you have an incompatible npm version.

`npm install -g npm@6.13.4`

The npm versions v3, v6 and v8 are partly incompatible. So just try to install a different npm version.

Answer (score 0):

npm registry -> It is the place where npm looks for information about the packages you asked for.

In layman language, we can say registry as public database where we can check available packages and download them.

Default npm public registry is found at https://registry.npmjs.org.

We can check the registry by running below command in your terminal:
npm config get registry.

To resolve 504 gateway timeout. Execute below command:
**npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/**